# Class 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade\Form' not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm new using Laravel and I got some problem. I'll try some option and search from internet but still not work. Trying to include forms functionalities with FormFacade with Laravel 5 and I keep getting this error :
[Error 1/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15O5v.png) 
[Error 2/2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjpEr.png)

I have added the following to config/app.php

```
Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

and

```
'Form'=> Illuminate\Html\FormFacade\Form::class,
'Html'=> Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade\Html::class,
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML & Form facades have been removed from Laravel 5.

To restore these facades, check [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html)

Comment: Hi, I go to the website and I put this code : "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"
and I still got error like this : http://s28.postimg.org/d4yrupjzx/image.png

Comment: If you are using Laravel 5.1, use `"laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"` instead

Answer (score 0):

You should update your composer by adding this dependency

```
"require": {
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"
}
```

But before sure that you `config/app.php` doesn't contain Html/Form service provider.

```
// Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
// Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

Check this link for further informations : https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html

Answer (score 0):

You mustn't install `Laravel Collective` to bring this feature back in Laravel 5.1. Install `illuminate/html` which comes with Laravel 4.

Simply complete this steps and you are good to go.

1. `composer require "illuminate/html":"5.0.*"`
2. Open `config/app.php` and update as follows:

   ```
   'providers' => [
      ...
      Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
   ],

   'aliases' => [
        ...

       'Form'=> Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class, 
       'Html'=> Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
   ],
   ```

Comment: Why you are saying that Laravel Collective should not be installed ?

Comment: I didn't say it should not be installed. However Laravel collective Installs many packages that have been removed in recent versions Laravel and illuminate/html is just one other them. Why install a collection of packages when you only need illuminate/html? Illuminate/html is officially Laravel package in Laravel 4. What Laravel collective does is install it and lots of other packages you don't even need.